# How to access Class's this inside a callback?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, this

I am playing around with ES6 and get stuck in "this". I have button and I want when a user click on button the text of button should be updated as "Passed".

**HTML**

```
<button type='button'>Click Me</button>
```

**JS**

```
class Test {
  constructor(){
    this.result = "Passed";
  }

  run() {
    alert('clicked');
    this.textContent = test.result;
  }

  btnClik() {
     document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', this.run ,false)
  }
}

let obj = new Test();
obj.btnClik();
```

You may see it in action:   [JSfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/35z5j143/)

Comment: You haven't really specified what the issue is, but likely you're looking for: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/476)

Comment: [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: I updated your fiddle, have a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of mistakes

- bind `this` context to the event handler
- set `textContent` of `event.target` instead of `this`

i.e.

```
  run(event) {
    event.target.textContent = this.result; //set target of event.target
  }

  btnClik() {
     document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', this.run.bind( this ) ,false); //notice bind this
  }
```

**Demo**

```js
class Test {
  constructor(){
    this.result = "Passed";
  }

  run(event) {
    event.target.textContent = this.result; //set target of event.target
  }

  btnClik() {
     document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', this.run.bind( this ) ,false); //notice bind this
  }
}

let obj = new Test();
console.log(obj);
obj.btnClik();
```

```html
<button type='button'>Click Me</button>
```